# Godot export to IOS failed

Tags: ios, xcode, godot

i want to export godot project to ios project. But when exporting, i got this "Project /godot_ios.xcodeproj cannot be opened because the project file cannot be parsed". 
Then i check using kin, and got results :

```
ERROR: line 50:133 mismatched input '$binary.entitlements' expecting {QUOTED_STRING, NON_QUOTED_STRING}
ERROR: line 53:139 mismatched input '$binary.app' expecting {QUOTED_STRING, NON_QUOTED_STRING}
ERROR: line 61:105 mismatched input '$binary.pck' expecting {QUOTED_STRING, NON_QUOTED_STRING}
ERROR: line 64:2 extraneous input '$additional_pbx_files' expecting REFERENCE
ERROR: line 89:4 extraneous input '$additional_pbx_frameworks_build' expecting {')', REFERENCE}
ERROR: line 104:4 extraneous input '$additional_pbx_resources_refs' expecting {';', 'runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing', ')', 'rootObject', REFERENCE}
ERROR: line 137:4 extraneous input '$additional_pbx_frameworks_refs' expecting {';', 'indentWidth', 'name', 'path', 'sourceTree', 'runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing', ')', 'rootObject', REFERENCE}
ERROR: line 150:10 mismatched input '$binary' expecting {QUOTED_STRING, NON_QUOTED_STRING}
ERROR: line 192:24 mismatched input '$team_id' expecting NON_QUOTED_STRING
ERROR: line 234:4 extraneous input '$additional_pbx_resources_build' expecting {';', 'indentWidth', 'name', 'path', 'sourceTree', 'runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing', ')', 'rootObject', REFERENCE}
ERROR: line 349:37 extraneous input '$binary.entitlements' expecting ';'
ERROR: line 374:37 extraneous input '$binary.entitlements' expecting ';'
```

How to export it to ios? 
i've download the template from godot official web, but give the same results.

Comment: Same problem, did you ever end up with a solution? I know this question is over a year old now.

Answer (score 0):

This question should be closed. Godot IOS export has been updated since the time of posting this question.